# Turning on JSDoc in VS Code produces "Cannot use JSX unless the '--jsx' flag is provided"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, create-react-app, jsdoc

I have React app created using Create React App. It uses ES6.

I am using JSDoc in this app to introduce type safety. Type safety is turned on using the following option in Visual Studio Code:

```
"javascript.implicitProjectConfig.checkJs": true
```

Type checking is working fine, except that any file that uses jsx is giving the following error.

> Cannot use JSX unless the '--jsx' flag is provided

This is because the project uses the `.js` extension for files containing JSX. There are too many files in the project so I don't want to change the extension to `.jsx`.

The only way I have found to shut up this warning is to add a tsconfig.json file with the follwoing content:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "jsx": "react"
    }
}
```

However, creating the tsconfig.json file creates other complications, e.g. tests are now breaking because CRA thinks that this is a TypeScript project, which is not true.

So the question is this: is there a way to suppress the "Cannot use jsx..." error without creating a tsconfig.json file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think using `jsconfig.json` is the best way in this case since your repo is a `js` repo. Now you just simply replace your above `tsconfig.json` with `jsconfig.json` located at the root level:

`jsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react"
  }
}
```

You can read me here to deal with `js` repo: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/working-with-javascript

Comment: So many answers were wrong in other places.  Thank you!

Comment: This answer is chocolate. Thanks man!